# Return Dictionary<string, string> or IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>

Tags: c#

From what I read best practices are to "always" expose interfaces from your classes.

So assuming that there is no need for the caller to receive a `Dictionary<string, string>`, should I just return `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, even if internally my class uses a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

My code is as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,long>> GetHddSize()
{
    var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

    var dictionary = drives.ToDictionary(drive => drive.Name, drive => drive.TotalSize);

    return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: Depends on your requirement.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal please elaborate.

Comment: It depends mostly on what you want to do there. Do you want the methods return value to always be used via a dictionary or that they can use something else (IEnumerable would allow the methods return value to be stored in a nondictionary, while dictionary only allows it to be stored in a dictionary...without conversions taht is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Dictionary<string, string>` is more than just an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

There are some cases where you wont care if you return an IEnumerable(mostly, when you want to enumerate a collection), but what happens when you want to add items from the outside? What about multiple keys that a Dictionary restricts and an IEnumerable doesn't?

There's a reason you're using a Dictionary in your code.

Comment: understand why in some cases you'd want a Dictionary returned for reasons like you said: adding data on the outside etc. In this case though, as you can see from the code, no items will be added outside at all and I don't really need to worry about multiple keys. Why not expose it as either a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, long>>` or `IDictionary<string, long>` in my particular case?

Comment: Let me ask you the opposite question: Why would you like to expose an interface of something concrete in this case? What will you get from this kind of action? I understand that 'it's better' to gain abstraction in most cases - but in this case I don't see the added value from converting a dictionary into an IEnumerable.

Comment: BTW, read about the 'yield' keyword if your into return IEnumerable's. returning an iterator on the fly may be powerful when you use it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what methods caller is intended to use. `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,long>>` looks ugly. If you want to return interface I suggest to return `IDictionary<string,long>`.

Comment: As I said, this is assuming that `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,long>>` contains everything that the caller requires, so don't need to worry about that. On another note, why do you say `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, long>>` looks ugly and `IDictionary<string,long>` would be better?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said, you still don't quite know how are you going to use return value of this method. That happens all the time when your coding.
In situations like this, I'd like to wrap data (in this case dictionary), in another class. Introducing a new class gives me lot of flexibility : I can later change it, extend it or force access policies. And if someday I realized I don't need it, I can refactor and remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but don't. Its provide a flexibility us, especially with collections. If you don't use another type data structures such Container  you probably won't need to use it.

I mean that if you working with different structures but same template such List or Queue you can use as you did. For example you can iterate both List and Queue in same code section.

I hope answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think IDictionary is a good choice for the reasons given by @Amir, plus the random access option of a dictionary which an enumeration doesn't provide. But I would not expose the Dictionary proper in case you want to replace it by something home grown. For example, Dictionary isn't serializable. IDictionary's interface is relatively slim and can be re-implemented if it will ever be necessary to replace your internal data holder with something else.